# Should you use version control for ctags?

Tags: git, ctags

I just setup a project with vim and ctags. Do ctags belong in my version control?

Thanks.

Comment: No, because that's a file you build/generate from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you shouldn't, (as jthill said) because that's a file you build/generate from source.

To add to jthill comment, you can find a complete configuration example in "[Supercharge your VIM into IDE with CTags](https://blog.sensible.io/2014/05/09/supercharge-your-vim-into-ide-with-ctags.html)"

ctags generate tag (index file of all the classes)

```
ctags -R --languages=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths)
```

But the .gitignore would always ignore those resulting tags.

Since you don't want to commit those files into the GIT index, add them to `.gitignore` or I like to add them to my global `~/.gitignore`.

```
$ cat <<EOT >> ~/.gitignore
tags
gems.tags
EOT
```

See [`github/gitignore/Global/Tags.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Tags.gitignore).